# Changing name of CSS every time the website code is updated in the server

Tags: html, css, heatmap

We are using a product called "mouseflow" which basically does heatmaps and user recordings. The problem is, because we are updating the site a few times a day (due to bugs found, UI/UX changes etc), the recordings in the dashboard doesnt seen normal. 
I would see something like this:

[image: Recordings error]

Here is the answer received from their support:

" It has to do with how we save the recorded pages on our end. We save the HTML shown to the visitor, but not the external resources like stylesheets, images and script-files. Those are loaded directly from your webserver. And if these files suddenly become available, it can throw off the playback and heatmaps.

In your case it seems you've recently made some updates to your live page, changing the filename of one of your stylesheets. The saved HTML was referencing the file 'https://mywebsite.com/app.e28780aef0c5d0f9ed85.css', which is no longer available on your server. Instead, you are now using the file 'https://mywebsite.com/app.20d77e2240a25ae92457.css'.

I suspect the filename of this stylesheet is automatically updated whenever the content is changed."

**The problem is** 
My tech team tells me that CSS file name always changes after its mimified and they really cant do anything about it. On the other hand, we really want to know what the user is actually seeing.

Is there any way around it? Can we have a stable file name even after mimifying the file?

Comment: Your tech team can either prevent the file names from changing or they can keep the old files around. When they tell you they can't do these things, what they're really saying is that they don't want to put in the effort necessary to make those changes. There's no valid technical reason that they can't do these things.

Comment: @Ouroborus I think the person i talked to didnt think it could happen. We exchanged a couple of suggestions and they said that file names will change and in a lot of places. We update our site almost 10 times a day. ( Yes, that's where we are at) Can you offer any suggestions perhaps? I will be really really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for you could be to copy the contents of the CSS files to a static file hosted on your server. The file should have a name that would never change (like mouseflow.css). Mouseflow could then insert a reference to that file, to load the needed CSS. This is something I know they can do quite easily.

You would need to manually update the static file, whenever major changes are made to the CSS on the livesite - but you wouldn't have to do it every time the file names changes.

Answer (score 0):

Like **Ouroborus** just said, there is no such thing as "we cant do anything about it". It is bounded to the way you or the designer leader tell how things will work.

Update the css 10 times a day isnt that much, so you can still manually changing the name the file name. If the file is called in a several files, but each file call the file again (not using an general header), so you can start work on it.

You also can keep an backup of all those old versions in your webserver.

And last, but not least, you can stop minifying your files, and work with something like SASS or LESS. Is way more productive and you will avoid this kind of issue.

Hope it helps you, and sorry about my english.

Best regards.

Comment: Using Sass or less is unrelated to the minification step. Plus the real culpirt here is that the filename has a content hash in it, to invalidate the cached version whenever there's a change, which is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The point of changing the file name is to invalidate the client cache. Every time your team makes changes, the filename changes, and the browser knows it needs to download it again. If the content hasn't changed between two visits, the file name will be the same, and the client browser will used a locally cached version of the file if it has any. 
So changing the filename makes the site update for everyone right after changes are published.

One solution is to remove the hash from the filename, and set a short cache duration, but that's bad for performance and not good practice.